# How to sort a vector in non-descending order without touching -1 values in R?

Tags: r, sorting, vector, numeric

The question:

"Some people are standing in a row in a park. There are trees between them which cannot be moved. Your task is to rearrange the people by their heights in a non-descending order without moving the trees. People can be very tall!"

Example

For

```
 a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180],
```

the output should be

```
 solution(a) = [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1,   180, 190].
```

We basically need to scan through this list and see where there a downstep (unless it is to a -1) and then find a way to re-order non -1 elements so that the list is non-ascending. I basically don't know where to even begin on this question. Would anyone give this a go in base R and talk me through your thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = c(-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180)
a[a>0] = sort(a[a>0])
a

[1]  -1 150 160 170  -1  -1 180 190
```

Explanation:

- `a>0` is boolean mask to get the non-trees values:

FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

If you apply it to `a` you get :

```
#a[a>0]
150 160 170 180 190
```

An thus you can order the values with  `sort(a[a>0])` and set back to the orignal vector using the same aproach with the boolean mask.

```
a[a>0] = sort(a[a>0])
```

Comment: No you are not, it takes some practice to get the R mentality that everything is a vector, we all struggled with this at the beginning ;) . Please mark the answer as the solution if it was helpful.